# Multiple marker on map

Tags: android

I want to show multiple users through markers on  map. I want my location should be in center with marker and others are around me. I want to show different image marker for every user. I don't want to use same image for all the users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these tutorials and use custom Images for each user

[Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

[Android: Double Taps on a MapView with Overlays](http://chrisblunt.com/2010/08/12/android-map-view-double-taps-and-overlay-markers/)